# pandas - pivot_table with non-numeric values? (DataError: No numeric types to aggregate)

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, dataframe

I'm trying to do a pivot of a table containing strings as results.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index' : range(8),
'variable1' : ["A","A","B","B","A","B","B","A"],
'variable2' : ["a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b"],
'variable3' : ["x","x","x","y","y","y","x","y"],
'result': ["on","off","off","on","on","off","off","on"]})

df1.pivot_table(values='result',rows='index',cols=['variable1','variable2','variable3'])
```

But I get: `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`.

This works as intended when I change result values to numbers:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'index' : range(8),
'variable1' : ["A","A","B","B","A","B","B","A"],
'variable2' : ["a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b"],
'variable3' : ["x","x","x","y","y","y","x","y"],
'result': [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]})

df2.pivot_table(values='result',rows='index',cols=['variable1','variable2','variable3'])
```

And I get what I need:

```
variable1   A               B    
variable2   a       b       a   b
variable3   x   y   x   y   x   y
index                            
0           1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1         NaN NaN   0 NaN NaN NaN
2         NaN NaN NaN NaN   0 NaN
3         NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   1
4         NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
5         NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   0
6         NaN NaN NaN NaN   0 NaN
7         NaN NaN NaN   1 NaN NaN
```

I know I can map the strings to numerical values and then reverse the operation, but maybe there is a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

My original reply was based on Pandas 0.14.1,  and since then,  many things changed in the pivot_table function (rows --> index,  cols --> columns... )

Additionally,  it appears that the original lambda trick I posted no longer works on Pandas 0.18. You have to provide a reducing function (even if it is min,  max or mean).  But even that seemed improper - because we are not reducing the data set,  just transforming it.... So I looked harder at unstack...

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index' : range(8),
'variable1' : ["A","A","B","B","A","B","B","A"],
'variable2' : ["a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b"],
'variable3' : ["x","x","x","y","y","y","x","y"],
'result': ["on","off","off","on","on","off","off","on"]})

# these are the columns to end up in the multi-index columns.
unstack_cols = ['variable1', 'variable2', 'variable3']
```

First,  set an index on the data using the index + the columns you want to stack,  then call unstack using the level arg.

```
df1.set_index(['index'] + unstack_cols).unstack(level=unstack_cols)
```

Resulting dataframe is below.

[image]

Comment: Finally a solution for replacing the pivot() changes in pandas 0.17.1

Comment: @RandallGoodwin, I realize this question is two years old, but I am getting the error "ValueError: Function does not reduce" using your lambda, off the top of your head would you know why?

Comment: Another idea:  if you will potentially have multiple values that appear, you could concat strings by making your `aggfunc = lambda x:  " ".join([str(y) for y in x])`

Comment: @dllahr  Same idea, but you can also use a variety of string accessors.  e.g. `aggfunc=lambda x: x.str.cat() ` FWIW, I used in an answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229444/trouble-pivoting-in-pandas-spread-in-r

Comment: @RustyShackleford  see comment by me or dllahr

Answer (score 2):

I think the best compromise is to replace on/off with True/False, which will enable pandas to "understand" the data better and act in an intelligent, expected way.

```
df2 = df1.replace({'on': True, 'off': False})
```

You essentially conceded this in your question. My answer is, I don't think there's a better way, and you should replace 'on'/'off' anyway for whatever comes next.

As Andy Hayden points out in the comments, you'll get better performance if you replace on/off with 1/0.

Comment: +1, though may be better to use 1 and 0 so as DataFrame has float rather than object dtype :)