# Trouble pivoting in pandas (spread in R)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot

I'm having some issues with the pd.pivot() or pivot_table() functions in pandas.

I have this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'site_id': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'b', 4: 'c', 5:
 'c',6: 'a', 7: 'a', 8: 'b', 9: 'b', 10: 'c', 11: 'c'},
                   'dt': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1,6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 2, 11: 2},
                   'eu': {0: 'FGE', 1: 'WSH', 2: 'FGE', 3: 'WSH', 4: 'FGE', 5: 'WSH',6: 'FGE', 7: 'WSH', 8: 'FGE', 9: 'WSH', 10: 'FGE', 11: 'WSH'},
                   'kw': {0: '8', 1: '5', 2: '3', 3: '7', 4: '1', 5: '5',6: '2', 7: '3', 8: '5', 9: '7', 10: '2', 11: '5'}})


df
Out[140]: 
    dt   eu kw site_id
0    1  FGE  8       a
1    1  WSH  5       a
2    1  FGE  3       b
3    1  WSH  7       b
4    1  FGE  1       c
5    1  WSH  5       c
6    2  FGE  2       a
7    2  WSH  3       a
8    2  FGE  5       b
9    2  WSH  7       b
10   2  FGE  2       c
11   2  WSH  5       c
```

I want this:

```
dt   site_id   FGE   WSH
 1         a     8     5
 1         b     3     7
 1         c     1     5
 2         a     2     3
 2         b     5     7
 2         c     2     5
```

I've tried everything!

```
df.pivot_table(index = ['site_id','dt'], values = 'kw', columns = 'eu')
```

or

```
df.pivot(index = ['site_id','dt'], values = 'kw', columns = 'eu')
```

should have worked. I also tried unstack():

```
df.set_index(['dt','site_id','eu']).unstack(level = -1)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your last try (with `unstack`) works fine for me, I'm not sure why it gave you a problem.  FWIW, I think it's more readable to use the index names rather than levels, so I did it like this:

```
>>> df.set_index(['dt','site_id','eu']).unstack('eu')

            kw    
eu         FGE WSH
dt site_id        
1  a         8   5
   b         3   7
   c         1   5
2  a         2   3
   b         5   7
   c         2   5
```

But again, your way looks fine to me and is pretty much the same as what @piRSquared did (except their answer adds some more code to get rid of the multi-index).

I think the problem with `pivot` is that you can only pass a single variable, not a list?  Anyway, this works for me:

```
>>> df.set_index(['dt','site_id']).pivot(columns='eu')
```

For `pivot_table`, the main issue is that 'kw' is an object/character and `pivot_table` will attempt to aggregate with `numpy.mean` by default.  You probably got the error message:  "DataError: No numeric types to aggregate".

But there are a couple of workarounds.  First, you could just convert to a numeric type and then use your same pivot_table command

```
>>> df['kw'] = df['kw'].astype(int)
>>> df.pivot_table(index = ['dt','site_id'], values = 'kw', columns = 'eu')
```

Alternatively you could change the aggregation function:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index = ['dt','site_id'], values = 'kw', columns = 'eu', 
                   aggfunc=sum )
```

That's using the fact that strings can be summed (concatentated) even though you can't take a mean of them.  Really, you can use most functions here (including lambdas) that operate on strings.

Note, however, that `pivot_table's` `aggfunc` requires some sort of reduction operation here even though you only have a single value per cell, so there actually isn't anything to reduce!  But there is a check in the code that requires a reduction operation, so you have to do one.

Comment: Ah I see. I was confused about why I would need aggfunc. Hopefully they remove that need in the next update :)

Answer (score 8):

```
df.set_index(['dt', 'site_id', 'eu']).kw \
    .unstack().rename_axis(None, 1).reset_index()
```

[image]